# mdadm: How to create RAID50 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: raid, mdadm, software-raid

I am unable to create a RAID50 with mdadm on Ubuntu 16.04. Every time I reboot the server, the RAID0 will disappear.

Here is how we proceeded to create the RAID50 :

Create two RAID5 (8 disks each) :

```
#Create RAID5 (md1)    
mdadm --create /dev/md1 -v --raid-devices=8 --level=5 /dev/nvme0n1 /dev/nvme1n1 /dev/nvme2n1 /dev/nvme3n1 /dev/nvme4n1 /dev/nvme5n1 /dev/nvme6n1 /dev/nvme7n1

#Create RAID5 (md2) 
mdadm --create /dev/md2 -v --raid-devices=8 --level=5 /dev/nvme8n1 /dev/nvme9n1 /dev/nvme10n1 /dev/nvme11n1 /dev/nvme12n1 /dev/nvme13n1 /dev/nvme14n1 /dev/nvme15n1
```

We waited for the disk to rebuild before creating the RAID0.

So far everything works as expected.

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
md2 : active raid5 nvme10n1[5] nvme15n1[3] nvme12n1[6] nvme8n1[2] nvme11n1[1] nvme14n1[8] nvme5n1[0] nvme2n1[4]
      21878398976 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/24 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid5 nvme13n1[8] nvme9n1[6] nvme7n1[2] nvme6n1[3] nvme4n1[4] nvme3n1[5] nvme1n1[1] nvme0n1[0]
      21878398976 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/24 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md126 : active raid1 sda[1] sdb[0]
      890796032 blocks super external:/md127/0 [2/2] [UU]

md127 : inactive sdb[1](S) sda[0](S)
      6306 blocks super external:imsm

unused devices: <none>
```

Once the RAID5 was fully rebuilt, we proceeded with the creation of the RAID0.

```
#Create RAID0 (md0) 
sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 -v --raid-devices=2 --level=0 /dev/md1 /dev/md2
```

Again it looks OK if we check it :

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid0 md2[1] md1[0]
      43756535808 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks

md2 : active raid5 nvme10n1[5] nvme15n1[3] nvme12n1[6] nvme8n1[2] nvme11n1[1] nvme14n1[8] nvme5n1[0] nvme2n1[4]
      21878398976 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 1/24 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid5 nvme13n1[8] nvme9n1[6] nvme7n1[2] nvme6n1[3] nvme4n1[4] nvme3n1[5] nvme1n1[1] nvme0n1[0]
      21878398976 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 1/24 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

md126 : active raid1 sda[1] sdb[0]
      890796032 blocks super external:/md127/0 [2/2] [UU]

md127 : inactive sdb[1](S) sda[0](S)
      6306 blocks super external:imsm

unused devices: <none>
```

As soon as I reboot, the RAID0 (md0) is gone.

```
md2 : active raid5 nvme10n1[5] nvme15n1[3] nvme12n1[6] nvme8n1[2] nvme11n1[1] nvme14n1[8] nvme5n1[0] nvme2n1[4]
      21878398976 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/24 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid5 nvme13n1[8] nvme9n1[6] nvme7n1[2] nvme6n1[3] nvme4n1[4] nvme3n1[5] nvme1n1[1] nvme0n1[0]
      21878398976 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/24 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md126 : active raid1 sda[1] sdb[0]
      890796032 blocks super external:/md127/0 [2/2] [UU]

md127 : inactive sdb[1](S) sda[0](S)
      6306 blocks super external:imsm
```

Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: mdadm.conf? dmesg, syslog of assembly process? raid on raid is possible but unusual, it might not be covered by auto detection.

Comment: if you're open to alternatives, why not raid6? with raid0 on raid5 you're pretty much gonna have two parities anyway, except you're still stuck on single redundance. otherwise LVM on RAID, and LVM also has a raid0 mode if that's a requirement. Not quite sure of your purpose / use case regarding raid0 on raid5.

Comment: @frostschutz What do you mean raid on raid is possible but unusual? This is all fairly new to me. Isn't the right way to create two RAID 5 with a span on top of it?

Comment: @frostschutz from what we have tested using fio (https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html), we achieve higher write performance with the following configuration.